# Trying to understand a simple Linux code

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I am trying to figure out What does the following command mean in linux

```
awk 'match($0, "##SA") ==0 {print $0} ' $1 > ${G_DEST_DIR}/${G_DEST_FILENAME}
```

Does it remove the 1st line from the given parameter and places it under dest_dir ?

Comment: Unclear why the original author wrote a highly unidiomatic Awk script when simply `grep -v '^##SA'` would be much easier both to read and to write.

Comment: `match(string, regexp [, array])`
Search string for the longest, leftmost substring matched by the regular expression, regexp and return the character position, or index, at which that substring begins (one, if it starts at the beginning of string). If no match is found, return zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This awk prints all lines from input file that don't match the pattern:

```
##SA
```

Output of this awk is redirected to file name represented by:

```
${G_DEST_DIR}/${G_DEST_FILENAME}
```

Note `$1` is shell variable here which is actually input file for awk.

Though same awk be shortened to:

```
awk '!/##SA/' "$1" > "${G_DEST_DIR}/${G_DEST_FILENAME}"
```

Comment: Oh, so if the pattern matches which is match($0, "##SA") ==0 do nothing or do not print otherwise print everything {print $0} is that right ? thanks alot

Comment: yes thats right, Thank you so much for your help. Appreciate it

Comment: Yes that's right `{print $0}` is default action so that can be omitted.